# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in Vitejs

Tags: reactjs, vite, es6-modules, commonjs

I am trying to build a react app with vitejs, the build is successful but when I try to serve it on browser I get this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I have tried all the options I get, here is my `vite.config.mts` file
I am not using `require` in my source code, the error is being thrown from a package named `redux-storage`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import { viteCommonjs, esbuildCommonjs } from '@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs';
import requireTransform from 'vite-plugin-require-transform';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    requireTransform({}),
    viteCommonjs(),
    react(),
    viteTsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin(),
  ],
  define: {
    'process.env': process.env,
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: {
        global: 'globalThis',
      },
      plugins: [esbuildCommonjs(['redux-storage'])],
    },
  },
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
});
```

[image]

[image]

##### Update:

Fixed this by installing `vite-plugin-commonjs` and adding it to `vite.config.js`
Basically added the package's `es` folder to the configuration

```
import commonjs from 'vite-plugin-commonjs';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    commonjs({
      filter(id) {
        if (id.includes('node_modules/redux-storage/build-es')) {
          return true;
        }
      },
    }),
    // Other plugins
  ],
  // Other configurations
});
```

Comment: Where and why are you using `require()`?

Comment: I am not using require, the error is coming from a package, which only uses commonJs

Comment: `redux-storage` seems abandoned. I doubt you'll get a fix any time soon

Comment: it is a pretty old package, `redux-storage`

Comment: Where in the package is `require()` used? What is the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: I have added screenshot in question

Comment: The update fix works. November 20, 2023